# Полиморфные связи Doctrine 2 использование промежуточной таблицы

Tags: php, symfony2, doctrine2

Имеется несколько сущностей (а в моем случае и одноименных таблиц mysql)

```
//==== общие схемы Таблиц ====

articles (
    id
    entity_type_id
)

posts (
    id
    entity_type_id
)

other... (
    id
    entity_type_id
)

//==== промежуточная таблица Типов ====

entity_types (
    id
)

//==== таблица Комментариев ====

comments (
    id
    entity_type_id
    entity_id
)
```

Я использую Doctrine 2 в связке с Symfony 2 и вот мое представление association mapping:

```
class Article
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityType", inversedBy="articles", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $entityType;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="article")
     */
    protected $comments;
}

class Post
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityType", inversedBy="posts", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $entityType;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="post")
     */
    protected $comments;
}
...

class EntityType
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="entityType")
     */
    protected $articles;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="entityType")
     */
    protected $posts;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="entityType")
     */
    protected $comments;
}

class Comment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityType", inversedBy="comments", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $entityType;

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="comments", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $article;

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="comments", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $post;
}
```

Встроенный отладчик Symfony2 мне говорит, что сущности у меня замаплены правильно, и вроде как все возможные операции выполняются, в том числе и добавление комментария к Article, но когда я пытаюсь комментить Post, получаю ошибку, связанную с тем, что entity_type_id = null и entity_id = null

как все-таки правильно замапить эти сущности?
спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Схема БД не соответсвует описанию моделей.

В вашем случае надо смотреть на [Single Table Inheritance.](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance)

Т.е. ваш код должен быть:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"article" = "Article", "post" = "Post"})
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $id; 

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="article")
     */
    protected $comments;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Post extends Article
{

}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Comment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="comments")
     */
    protected $article;
}
```